# Using Flink to get Counts Within a Keyed Window

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm using Flink via the Scala interface to do some data processing. I have some user data that comes in tuples:

```
(user1, "titanic")
(user1, "titanic")
(user1, "batman")
(user2, "star wars")
(user2, "star wars")
(user2, "batman")
```

I want to key by the user, create a window and then count the number of times that a user has viewed a particular movie within that window, so that I end up with a Map from each movie to the number of view counts for each user. For example, for `user1`, the correct output is `Map("titanic" -> 2, "batman" -> 1)`.
I know that the first part of my code should look something like this:

`keyedStream.keyBy(0).window(EventTimeSessionWindows.withGap(Time.minutes(10)))`

But I don't know how to do a further aggregation within the window so that I end up with a Map of view counts for each user/window. I've attempted to write my own AggregateFunction that collects these counts into a mutable Map but unfortunately a mutable Map is not serializable, so it fails.

How might I do this?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what your ultimate question is.

Comment: I'm wondering how I might aggregate over the tuples in the window so that the output is a Map that goes from the movie to the number of times the user has seen that movie. I haven't been able to do this with my own AggregateFunction since a scala Map isn't serializable. Is there a way around that? Or is there some other way to do the aggregation?

Comment: I think you want to do a `keyby`, then a `map` which extends a `RichMapFunction`. It will allow you to save a `MapState` in which you can keep track of your count. If you don't want to use `MapState` you can refer to [wordcount example](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-examples/flink-examples-batch/src/main/scala/org/apache/flink/examples/scala/wordcount/WordCount.scala) and `groupby` user and movie, and sum(1).

Comment: I'll give that a shot and report back. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to solve the problem by using an `AggregateFunction`:

```
source
  .keyBy(0)
  .timeWindow(Time.seconds(10L))
  .aggregate(new AggregateFunction[(String, String), (String, Map[String, Int]), (String, Map[String, Int])] {
    override def createAccumulator(): (String, Map[String, Int]) = ("", Map())

    override def add(value: (String, String), accumulator: (String, Map[String, Int])): (String, Map[String, Int]) = {
      val counter = accumulator._2.getOrElse(value._2, 0)
      (value._1, accumulator._2 + (value._2 -> (counter + 1)))
    }

    override def getResult(accumulator: (String, Map[String, Int])): (String, Map[String, Int]) = accumulator

    override def merge(a: (String, Map[String, Int]), b: (String, Map[String, Int])): (String, Map[String, Int]) = {
      (a._1, (a._2.keySet ++ b._2.keySet) map (k => k -> (a._2.getOrElse(k, 0) + b._2.getOrElse(k, 0))) toMap)
    }
  })
```